# Duda sobre el símbolo de tilde en Php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Quiero saber por que aparece el símbolo de tilde a un lado del número de valores de una tabla de PhpMyAdmin

Lo único que se es que aparece cuando la cifra es muy grande.

Adjunto la imagen para que vean a que tilde me refiero.

Gracias

[image: Interfaz de PhpMyAdmin]

Comment: Es una aproximación. No hay un valor cierto, pero tiene esta aproximación de acuerdo a los stats más recientes que tiene disponibles. Entonces, el símbolo que ves se usa para decir _aprox_

Comment: Algo así imaginaba, muchas gracias amigo por tu respuesta :-)